# How can I replace this line in Bash?

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line

I need to replace this line through a Bash script:

```
$config['language'] = "english";
```

With this line:

```
$config['language'] = "french";
```

The file path is *application/config/config.php*

Comment: Please note that SO isn't exactly for "please write my tools for me" requests... we like to help people _learn_ how to program. What have you tried already? How did it fail?

Comment: @sarnold I actually tried several variations of sed but I failed because of $['=; chars. Next times I'll try to post what I tried before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed double quote issue

```
sed -i '' -e "s/\$config\['language'\] = \"english\";/\$config['language'] = \"french\";/" application/config/config.php
```

p.s. Originally, you have single quotes around your languages, anyway - the regex is fixed now

Comment: don't encourage such questions by answering them

Comment: That's not working for me. Also, the var value is enclosed in double not single quotes. Thanks.

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry about the confusion. The character after the = sign is a tab not a space.

Comment: @emurad: use "\t" in the regex to match a tab

Comment: Is this working for you on this file: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/72bf2f06cb5d/application/config/config.php? I tried it but it didn't work.